# Links from Analytics go to another website

Tags: google-analytics

I have a very urgent problem. I have started to help a friend with SEO and the first thing I did was checking her website data. The problem is that when - in Google Analytics - I relate the landing page with the acquisition channel and I check where the traffic goes, I do not land on the website but on another website: adsagency.com which is listed in the Referral Exclusion List. What does it mean and how can I solve it?

Comment: Have you done an audit with something like ScreamingFrog or SEO PowerSuite or anything similar? Have you checked the ad providers for the site? Have you checked the site for signs of having been compromised? What CMS is being used and is it and all themes and plug-ins up to date? Have you checked them for vulnerabilities here? https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/search?execution=e2s1 Adsagency.com may be legitimate. However, it is an overseas firm. What audience does this site serve? Is it an appropriate ad firm for the site? Cheers!!

Comment: CMS is Wordpress. Found the problem! The Website's URL in Admin was wrong. By the way i did not set Google Analytics by myself - probably the old webmaster did it! OMG